# Categorical Binary Variable

Tags: survey, non-response

I'm attempting to draw an inference of accuracy be it by confidence interval or response rate, except typical methods don't really suite my problem for the reason that the entire population was surveyed for a yes or no vote. The 'sample' of data which is categorical binary variables, then is simply the proportion of the population that responded, which was 63% n=47.

Accordingly, the non response isn't represented as it is in typical literature, whereby non response is framed in the proportion of response within a sample taken from the population and not where the entire population is surveyed.

Further, central limit theorem seems to be empirically more robust regarding continuous data and particular parameters such as mean. Which is not to say that the convergence and attractor functions will not be relevant here.

I'm assuming both ways of framing the problem are empirically descriptive, but I am struggling to frame the issue with technical precision.

Any input would be great.

Comment: If you have measurements of the entire population in question, why do you need inference?

Comment: Well I don't have complete population data, the entire population was surveyed, but only 63% responded. I am trying to consider in terms of some theories I am somewhat familiar with, whether this is representative given any peculiarities with this type of variable. The 'sample' seems to be large enough to be accurate and I don't see that the non response is 'caused' by an attribute of the variable.

Comment: Let me see if I understand the problem -- is it that you're wondering how the population as a whole (including the currently nonresponding individuals) would vote if forced to?  Your hesitation about generalizing your results to current non-responders makes sense (see for example the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-response_bias), but the extent to which we worry about this problem depends on the nature of the investigation -- can you tell us more about why you worry about nonresponse in this population?

Comment: Essentially my query is that even though I surveyed the entire population, I am, through non response, left with a sample. Can I apply the conclusions of non response literature which seem to indicate even much lower rates of response provide accurate population estimates even though the situation isn't exactly analogous as I mentioned. And further, can CLT be held to operate on this type of variable and data point it generates?

Comment: Thanks Mark, that is my concern. I'm dealing with a policy decision based on this hesitation concerning generalizing the result. This is not an income survey or a variable that I think should impact non response, it's a yes or no survey to determine an hours of work change. I will check that article.

Comment: a 63% response rate is not at all unusual in the social sciences.. it (often times) is just difficult to get people to take surveys.  My intuition here would be to treat non-responders as though they were essentially ambivalent.  Similar to gung's idea above, your survey method (sampling *all* members of the population) means that you don't really need to use statistical inference in order to estimate an unobserved parameter.  Instead, you've actually just found that parameter by brute force.

Comment: I am inclined to agree that non responders are ambivalent and was considering reviewership bias as related, wherein people who do respond or review feel strongly: yes/no, or 1/5 or 5/5 stars. Yes basically I have a very large sample as a proportion of population. The thing that probably makes inference more unwarranted is that the binary variable yields no variance. The problem with these things is that besides inference, is that testing for the impact of non response is limited by that non response.